# How can I avoid site search page duplicate title tag error in pagination of site search?

Tags: google-search-console, web-crawlers

Google Search Console shows me my site search page duplicate Title Tag,

[image]

Comment: Google sometimes penalizes sites that allow their site search results to be indexed: https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/search-results-in-search-results/

Answer (score 2):

Your specific issue in this case is not the pagination, but that each page itself is actually a duplicate, living at two different URLs:

`/entertainment/...` and `/Entertainment/...`

To fix this, either set up 301 redirects to the canonical version of the page (the "real url" you want the page to have), or specify the canonical url of each page in a meta `canonical` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can block these search result pages in the robots.txt file, that can also be beneficial for your crawl budget.

If that is not a desired option for you, then you could try to add the search query to the title tag in order to make it unique.

Alternatively, you can just ignore the title tag error in Google Webmaster Tools.

Comment: You can block these search result pages in the robots.txt file : how to do that?

Comment: This pages describes that process well: http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html